# Remote Desktop that doesn't go through the cloud

Tags: macos, ios, remote-desktop

What is a simple and cheap solution that let's me see and control my OSX desktop from iOS that solely works over LAN and does not connect to the internet at any time?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of VNC clients in the App Store. If you put "VNC" in the search field, you should be able to easily see what's available in your geographic region and sort the wheat from the chaff.